# How to have the same attribute name reference two different types in the same namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

All my XML attributes are in a different namespace, so my XSD references them from the other XSD. I have two different elements with an attribute with the same name, but different types.

```
<integer ons:name="10" />
<string ons:name="string"/>
```

So the `integer` element has a `ons:name` attribute that is an `integer` while the `string` element has a `ons:name` attribute that is a `string`.

How do I define that in the XSD? Currently I have:

```
<xs:element name="integer">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute ref="ons:name" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then in the second XSD for the `ons` namespace I have the following:

Then the problem is for the second element's attribute there is no way to specify the `type` with the `ref`, and if the `ref` references a different attribute then it gets a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the schema document for namespace `ons`, define two singleton attribute groups:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="name-int">
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:integer" use="required" form="qualified"/>
</xs:attribute-group>

<xs:attributeGroup name="name-str">
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" form="qualified"/>
</xs:attribute-group>
```

Then reference the attribute group from the complex type:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="ons:name-int"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Not working for me. The `name` attribute is in the default namespace instead of the `ons` namespace.

Comment: Edited the answer to add form="qualified".